# Calculate the geodesic of Z = XY between two points

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geodesic

I have only learned about calculus and linear algebra, so I don't know about differential algebra.

I got to know about the concept of "geodesic" recently. What I need to know is this:

> Suppose I have a $10\times 10$ matrix $Z$ and $Z = XY$, where $X$ is $10\times 3$, $Y$ is $3\times 10$. I have two points in a manifold, $(X_1, Y_1, Z_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2, Z_2)$. I want to calculate the "geodesic path" between this two point in this manifold which satisfy $Z=XY$. How can I do that?

At present, I think the idea may be similar with how to calculate the geodesic path between two point $(x_1, y_1, z_2)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ which satisfy $z=xy$ in a $3$-dimensional space. But I don't know how to calculate the simplified case easier, as I know nothing about differential geometry.

I'm looking forward to your response!

Comment: Hi @bangliu. Welcome! You might find [this MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful for this site in future :)

Comment: Interesting problem.  It's weird enough to have to associate matrices with coordinates, but even weirder for two coordinates to be matrices of different sizes.  What is the context of such a problem?

Comment: @Muphrid The context is: consider the Z matrix is the some kind of "distance" matrix, and Z(i,j) is the distance between iten i and j. Maybe you may ask that Z should be symmetric, but the thing is Z(i,j) and Z(j, i) maybe a little different. Now I want to know how this matrix changes during a time period. I know Z1 and Z2, and I want to inference Z between time t1~t2 using the "geodesic path". If you haven't met the case of matrix, could you help me with the simplified case: z=xy in the 3-dimentional space? Thanks!

Comment: @Shaun Hi, thanks, the link is helpful!

Comment: @Muphrid Maybe more detailed: for example, in a network, we have N nodes, the latency between node i, j is Z(i,j). The latency matrix can be factorized as two matrices multiplication: Z = XY, where X is N*r, and Y is r*N.

Comment: Then I think you want to look into graph theory. Differential geometry deals with continua of points. Graph theory deals with discrete, interconnected nodes.

Comment: @Muphrid But how about the 3-dimensional case? The geodesic of z = xy surface between two points.

Comment: @Muphrid As I said, I learned about Linear Algebra and Claculous, but I don't know about differential geometry. So maybe the simplified question is simple, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to learn from a book, but usually it start from a lot of symbols and definitions. I want to know from this simple example on the surface of z=xy, then I will try to learn more from books or papers. Thanks!

Comment: I really think differential geometry here is like bringing a screwdriver to hammer a nail.  Your $Z$ doesn't really represent a point, or a particular surface, but rather it describes the pathway between two nodes.  That's exactly the kind of thing graph theory is good at doing: finding the shortest route between two nodes.

Comment: @Muphrid Yeah, I understand what you mean. However, I still want to know the answer to the simplified question, which is not related to matrix or network nodes. Could you help me with this question? Thanks!

Comment: @Jesse Madnick Hi，I think maybe you can help.